# Wireless passwords are seen by all users

Tags: wireless, password

Wireless passwords are seen by all users who use a Ubuntu machine. How do I prevent this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/218316/how-can-i-prevent-desktop-users-from-viewing-the-wireless-password

I think that's what you need :)

Comment: @maikati I would post this as a answer. Might help the OP...

Comment: Hope my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/595091/295286) may be useful to some