# Wireless password not protected

Tags: wireless, password

This might be a security issue. In Ubuntu 14.10, 14.04... under  **-network connections/edit wi-fi/wi-fi security  -** my wireless password is shown and it can be seen by anyone who can access my computer.

Can I protect my password? Is there any application which will ask for root access? To whom shall I report this problem?

Comment: do not use a single account for all users. I suggest you use the guest account for non-trusted users . Lock you screen or log out when you leave your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that is not an option for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal - Ubuntu has this out of the box.

What you can do, is restrict access to the actual command that allows you editing network settings, the `nm-connnection-editor`.

Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and enter the following commands:

1. `ls -l $(sudo which nm-connection-editor)` ; This will show current permissions for the nm-connection-editor

2.`sudo chmod 700 $(sudo which nm-connection-editor)` ; this will change the permissions

3. Repeat the command #1, to make sure you have changed the permissions. Now try editing the connections.

**NOTE** : in case you ever want to go back to editing , you will need to enter this command `sudo chmod 755 $(sudo which nm-connection-editor)` to make the editor accessible again

Comment: If you found this question useful, leave an upvote and a comment. Thanks

Comment: This is bad Following your instructions you can no longer edit connections but the problem lies in trying to reverse which gives a chmod: missing operand after '700' error

Comment: `sudo chmod 700 $(sudo which nm-connection-editor)`. Also there is extra space between $( and which. I will need to edit that, brb. Also , when you go back, your permissions have to be 755, not 700. 700 is to make only root able to access the nm-connection-editor

Comment: My bad I left out sudo  it works

Comment: No problem  :) I should have caught that space right away - that's what happens when you rush typing -_-'

Comment: Thanks, not really what I was looking for, but it works. Off course, it is much better than no protection at all!

Comment: @VRR What do you mean ? change how ?

Comment: @VRR It's not done out of the box because you want people to be able to configure anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer provided earlier I was going for a different direction and after some research created another answer.

After creating wi-fi connection the next step would be to edit the keyfile corresponding to it. With root permissions, edit the keyfile which is  located in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.

Within *[wifi-security]* section add the *psk flag* below your password:

```
psk=yourpassword
psk-flags=1
```

It is added to make sure the password maintain non visible. Now, the connection's properties cannot be changed without typing the password. The drawback is that *Network Manager* must be restarted in case you want to disconnect/connect again, otherwise you will have to type in password each time. For that we can use a script, but note you must uncheck autoconnect option with this method. Open text editor and paste following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$2" = "down" ];then
    case "$CONNECTION_UUID" in
        12e5ffbb-ec82-465a-a405-04e5072cebba)
        service network-manager restart;;
        *) ;;
    esac
fi
exit 0
```

Replace UUID from script with the one from your connection (or pipe several for multiple connections). It can be retrieved with `nmcli connection show` command. Save the script to your home folder and name it *restart_wireless*. Then move it to `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` folder:

```
sudo mv '~/restart_wireless' /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d
```

and change permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/restart_wireless'
```

At this point you might experience password being visible after logout/login. It is due to default keyring setting. To prevent this you might add new item to *Startup Applications*:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --components=secrets
```

and all pass-phrases will be flushed each time you login. Do this only if you don't have other applications corresponding to your keyring settings.

Restart for effect.

After this procedure Wi-Fi password is not shown in Network Connections:

[image]

## PROS:

- password cannot be accessed with command line tools
- there is no need to [alter GNOME Keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Tips_and_tricks) settings
- ability to use Network connections GUI
- ability to use Wi-fi connection within Guest session 
  (although it might be interesting to reproduce those restrictions as well)

## CONS:

- cannot use *'Automatically connect to this network when is available'* option
- passwords will be flushed each time on login

[Source](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#WPA-PSK_and_WPA2-PSK)